# Low AKS Cluster utilization

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, autoscaling

My AKS cluster is always low in utilisation. I can see its using 20-30% of CPU/Memory and using extra nodes and never scaling down on the nodes. Its running an airflow instance which can spike utilization to 60% when running DAGs for short bursts.

How do I make sure it doesn't use extra nodes so we can manage costs effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Following link would be helpful -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler